# How to find IP-Address ranges from list of IP addresses

Tags: networking

I have around 20000 IP Addresses. and I am looking to find the network-block-ranges for these IP addresses. The purpose is to provide information to have hole in the firewall so that these addresses can be allowed. I can looking in a.b.c.d/x bits format. There could be several ranges.

Update: I have IP Addresses already in my apache log files, rather than creating new ones.

Comment: IP addresses don't "belong" to blocks. Could you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: See the update: I am trying to figure out ranges of the existing IP Addresses.

Comment: Yes, we realise that, but that doesn't change the fact that you can't determine a network block from an IP address.

Answer (score 5):

You can't determine this from the addresses. You need to know the subnet masks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). 20000 < 2^15. So you need  a free A.B.C.D/15 block, but AFAIK /15 block is not common, while /16 is accepted one. So you need A.B.C.D/16.

Comment: I am trying to figure out ranges of the existing IP Addresses from my log files rather than requesting new ones.

Comment: Then you can sort the IP addresses and both biggest ans smallest one will give you a clue for the CIDR subnet mask.

Comment: I have existing IP Addresses and I can have easily  more than one subnet.

Comment: So, there're no answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find them programatically? If your answer is yes, i'll give a solution for it in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String originalIP = "a.b.c.d/x";
    String[] ipParts = originalIP.split("[\\.\\/]");

    boolean ipWithinBounds = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < ipParts.length; i++) {
        ipWithinBounds &= withinBounds(Integer.parseInt(ipParts[0]), 
                                        lowerBound, upperBound);
    }
}

public static boolean withinBounds(int check, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    if(check >= lowerBound && check <= upperBound)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This won't work unless you change the originalIP variable to a real IP.

Comment: Hi,
 Can you care to explain the algorithm?
 I might be looking for recursive solution.

Comment: Sorry it appears that I've misunderstood your question. You want, given a set of IPs find the ranges that contains them all?